# How did Indonesia become Muslim?

Tags: history, conversion

In my kids' history books the Islamic conquests always seem to end around Pakistan, but clearly Indonesia is the most populous Islamic country in the world today.  When and what methods did Islam come to Indonesia? Were the original religions treated similar to how Christians were treated in the conquests of Roman Empires in the 700's?

Comment: I doubt that this is on-topic on this site as it is not about Islamic teachings. Maybe try [History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I guess even on HistorySE it would be regareded as off-topic if wikipedia offers some information.